# How do I hide 2 incorrect answers from array list and enable 2 possible answer?

Tags: android, button

I have 4 buttons and **I want to hide 2 incorrect answers from the list** every time I click the help `button`.My problem is how can I **enable the specific answer**? All-thought I know the correct but when I click help `button` the correct answer is also selected to hide.How can set the correct answer to show and random hide 2 incorrect answer? I used 
`button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` and       `button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` to hide and show the `button`.

here is my code bellow.

```
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity {

MediaPlayer mySound;
List<Question> quesList;
int qid = 0;

//for help 50/50
int help =0;
int score = 0;
int rnd2 ,rnd1;

ProgressBar progressBar;
private static  MyCountDownTimer myCountDownTimer;
// Animation
Animation animFadein;
Question currentQ;
TextView txtQuestion, scored;
Button button1, button2, button3, button4,helpbtn;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;


public void help (View view){
    helpbtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.helpbtn);
    helpbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setEnabled(false);
            help = help -1;

            if(help == 0){
                helpbtn.setEnabled(false);

            }
            if (help > 0){
                helpbtn.setEnabled(true);

            }

            String AnswerString = currentQ.getANSWER();
            //match DB answer to selected answer, turn it visible if it is correct
            if(button1.getText().equals(AnswerString)){
                button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if(button2.getText().equals(AnswerString)){
                button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if(button3.getText().equals(AnswerString)){
                button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if(button4.getText().equals(AnswerString)){
                button4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //random hide 2 incorrect answers
            List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
            Collections.shuffle(list);
            rnd1 = list.get(0);
            rnd2 = list.get(1);

            /*int answer = 2; // Correct answer
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
            rnd1 = list.get(0);
            rnd2 = list.get(1);
            for(int i = 1; i<= 4 ; i++) {
                if (i != answer) {
                    list.add(i);
                }
            }*/

            if ((rnd1 == 1) || (rnd2 == 1)){
                button1.getText().equals(AnswerString);
                button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if ((rnd1 == 2) || (rnd2 == 2)){
                button2.getText().equals(AnswerString);
                button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if ((rnd1 == 3) || (rnd2 == 3)){
                button3.getText().equals(AnswerString);
                button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if ((rnd1 == 4) || (rnd2 == 4)){
                button4.getText().equals(AnswerString);
                button4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_qestion);
    QuizHelper db = new QuizHelper(this);  // my question bank class
    quesList = db.getAllQuestions();  // this will fetch all questions
    currentQ = quesList.get(qid); // the current question
    mySound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bensoundcute); // music background
    mySound.start();
    mySound.setLooping(true);
    mySound.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    txtQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);
    // load the textQuestion animation
    animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_in);
    // the text view in which the question will be displayed
    // the 4 buttons,
    // the idea is to set the text of 4 buttons with the options from question bank
    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    // the text view in which score will be displayed
    scored = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    // method which will set the things up for our game
    setQuestionView(false);
    txtQuestion.setAnimation(animFadein);
    txtQuestion.startAnimation(animFadein);


    // button click listeners
    final MediaPlayer buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.play);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonSound.start();
            // passing the button text to other method
            // to check whether the answer is correct or not
            // same for all three buttons
            getAnswer(button1.getText().toString());
            if(myCountDownTimer != null) {
                myCountDownTimer.cancel(); // Stop Timer
            }
            progressBar.setProgress(100);
            myCountDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(30000, 500);
            myCountDownTimer.start();


        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonSound.start();
            getAnswer(button2.getText().toString());
            if(myCountDownTimer != null) {
                myCountDownTimer.cancel(); // Stop Timer
            }
            progressBar.setProgress(100);
            myCountDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(30000, 500);
            myCountDownTimer.start();

        }
    });
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonSound.start();
            getAnswer(button3.getText().toString());
            if(myCountDownTimer != null) {
                myCountDownTimer.cancel(); // Stop Timer
            }
            progressBar.setProgress(100);
            myCountDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(30000, 500);
            myCountDownTimer.start();

        }
    });
    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonSound.start();
            getAnswer(button4.getText().toString());
            if(myCountDownTimer != null) {
                myCountDownTimer.cancel(); // Stop Timer
            }
            progressBar.setProgress(100);
            myCountDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(30000, 500);
            myCountDownTimer.start();
        }
    });
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

    // Create custom dialog object

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(QuestionActivity.this ,android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);

    // Include dialog.xml file
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);


    // Set dialog title
    // set values for custom dialog components - text, image and button
    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textDialog);
    text.setText("Everytime you get 5 Correct answer, youre help points increases, use this help points to elemenate 2 incorrect answer");
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    dialog.show();
    Button declineButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.declineButton);
    // if decline button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    declineButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Close dialog
            dialog.cancel();
            buttonSound.start();

            if(myCountDownTimer != null) {
                myCountDownTimer.cancel(); // Stop Timer
            }
            progressBar.setProgress(100);
            myCountDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(30000, 500);
            myCountDownTimer.start();

        }
    });
}
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
public Action getIndexApiAction() {
    Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
            .setName("Question Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
            .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
            .build();
    return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
            .setObject(object)
            .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
    client.disconnect();
    myCountDownTimer.cancel();
}

public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        int progress = (int) (millisUntilFinished/300);
        Log.v("Log_tag", "Timer Progress "  + millisUntilFinished);
        progressBar.setProgress(progress);
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        if(myCountDownTimer != null) {
            myCountDownTimer.cancel(); // Stop Timer
        }
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        myCountDownTimer.cancel();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Times Up!.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        if (score > 49){
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,
                    Successresult.class);
            // passing the int value
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
            intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
            setQuestionView(false);
            myCountDownTimer.cancel();
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,
                    ResultActivity.class);
            // passing the int value
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
            intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
            setQuestionView(false);
            startActivity(intent);
            myCountDownTimer.cancel();
            finish();
        }
    }



}
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    mySound.release();
    finish();
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to Exit?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //if user pressed "yes", then he is allowed to exit from application
            dialog.dismiss();
            onYesClick();
        }
        private void onYesClick() {
            Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(setIntent);
            myCountDownTimer.cancel();
            finish();
            QuestionActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //if user select "No", just cancel this dialog and continue with app
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
public void getAnswer(String AnswerString) {
    myCountDownTimer.cancel();
    Log.d("TIMER", "timer canceled");
    Log.d("Tag", "score = " + score + ", help = " + help +" remaining");
    if(myCountDownTimer != null) {
        myCountDownTimer.cancel(); // Stop Timer
    }

    if (currentQ.getANSWER().equals(AnswerString)) {
        // if conditions matches increase the int (score) by 1
        // and set the text of the score view

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CORRECT!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        score++;
        scored.setText("Score:  " + score + " /100");
        if(score % 5 == 0) {
            help = help+1;
            Log.d("Tag", "score = " + score + ", help = " + help);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your help Encreases", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    else {
        Log.d("TIMER", "timer canceled");
        myCountDownTimer.cancel();
        // if unlucky start activity and finish the game
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! Better luck next time.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (score > 49){
            myCountDownTimer.cancel();
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,
                    Successresult.class);
            // passing the int value
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
            intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
            setQuestionView(false);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,
                    ResultActivity.class);
            // passing the int value
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
            intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
            setQuestionView(false);
            myCountDownTimer.cancel();
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
    if(qid < 101) {
        // if questions are not over then do this
        currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
        setQuestionView(true);
        txtQuestion.setAnimation(animFadein);
        txtQuestion.startAnimation(animFadein);
        button1 .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        button2 .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        button3 .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        button4 .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        myCountDownTimer.cancel();
        // if unlucky start activity and finish the game
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Game Over.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (score > 49){
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,
                    Successresult.class);
            // passing the int value
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
            intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
            setQuestionView(false);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,
                    ResultActivity.class);
            // passing the int value
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
            intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
            setQuestionView(false);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
private boolean setQuestionView(boolean b) {
    // the method which will put all things together

    txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
    button1.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
    button2.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
    button3.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
    button4.setText(currentQ.getOPTD());

    qid++;
    return b;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SanjayHirani is on the right track so I'll go with a modified version of his answer.  Try this...

```
    int answer = getAnswerNumber();
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 1; i<= 4 ; i++) {
        if (i != answer) {
            list.add(i);
        }
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    int rnd1 = list.get(0);
    int rnd2 = list.get(1);
```

I was testing with a reduced version of your code so my getAnswerNumber was a bit different but here's what I think will work for you.

```
private int getAnswerNumber() {
    // returns 1 if none of the button text matches the answer, hopefully this won't happen
    int answerNumber = 1;         

    if (button1.getText().equals(AnswerString)) {
        answerNumber = 1;
    } else if (button2.getText().equals(AnswerString)) {
        answerNumber = 2;
    } else if (button3.getText().equals(AnswerString)) {
        answerNumber = 3;
    } else if (button4.getText().equals(AnswerString)) {
        answerNumber = 4;
    }

    Log.d("Quiz" , "answer no. = " + answerNumber);
    return answerNumber;
}
```

Comment: WOW! :D thank you sir @Garry99 it works ^_^ this is the best answer..Thank You So Much!!!!!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

In this list don't add the number that is the correct answer,
    List list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);

i.e: if correct answer is 2 then set List as following

```
        int answer = 2; // Correct answer
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 1; i<= 4 ; i++) {
            if(i != answer) {
                list.add(i);
            }
        }
```

So when you get random number the answer button will not be hidden

Comment: Thank you Sir for the fast reply. I already try your codes but the help button is disable not the 4 buttons..i will edit my codes in the question

Comment: You have not initialized rnd1 and rnd2 so they will always be 0

Comment: How can I initialized it? i don't know what's the code Sir for that.

Comment: rnd1 and rnd2 are the random numbers that you want out of that list.

Comment: what's wrong with my codes sir? i edit my codes in the question..i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you should make the other buttons Visible,while your hiding the reuired button