# How to set click limit of clicking a button? click limit is equal to score over 5

Tags: java, android, button, onclicklistener

How can I set a limit of clicking a button? The number  of click is equal to **score % 5**.Example score is equal to 15 the number of click limit is equal to 3 how can I do that? my codes is not working

```
  int score = 0;
  int help = score % 5;


   if (score == help) {
                helpbtn.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                 helpbtn.setEnabled(true);
            }
```

I put it inside of

> public void onClick(View v) {    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you need now.  I've made some assumptions.  I added a separate button to submit answers and I added a boolean that is always true for now.  I did manage to use modulo in this version though.  Hope this helps.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private int score = 0;
    private int help = 0;
    private boolean answerCorrect = true;       // dummy set always true for now
    private Button answerButton = null;         
    private Button hlpbtn = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        answerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_answer);
        answerButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        hlpbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_help);
        hlpbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        hlpbtn.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId() == R.id.button_answer) {
            if(answerCorrect) {
                if((++score % 5) == 0) {
                    ++help;
                }
                if((help > 0) && !hlpbtn.isEnabled()) {
                    hlpbtn.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
            Log.d("Quiz", "score = " + score + ", help = " + help);
        } else if(view.getId() == R.id.button_help) {
            if(--help <= 0) {
                hlpbtn.setEnabled(false);
                Log.d("Quiz", "help button disabled");
            }
            Log.d("Quiz", "help pressed, " + help + " remaining");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir @Gary99 i understand your codes.But my problem is how can I add the number of limit? I'm working for a quiz app. Every 5 correct answer is plus 1 to help button :)

Comment: I've made another attempt.  I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank You sir @Garry99 I Accept your answer :)  ^_^  I get the  idea in your first comment before you edit :)

Comment: Thanks,  glad I could help.

Comment: I had a last problem in my quiz. here the link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41057972/how-do-i-hide-2-incorrect-answers-from-array-list-and-enable-2-possible-answer/41058156?noredirect=1#comment69324349_41058156 I don't know how to enable the correct answer..can you help me sir? :)

Comment: I'll be happy to look at it but it is late here so it will have to be tomorrow.

Comment: Okay sir Thank's a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

If in the example limit is 3, then :

```
if(help>0)

    { 
      //logic;

      help--;
    }
```

you can add it in else block.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want `15 / 5` instead of `15 % 5`.

`15 / 5 == 3`, whereas `15 % 5 == 0`.

Comment: yes just like that Sir @Extragorey i want the number of click is equal to score divided by 5..I already use the / but i only get 1 click my help button is not adding..

Answer (score 0):

15/5 =3. Try this, this will help you to click a button 3 times.
%it gives remainder. Ie --->15%5=0